# Promotional Grant: DC Comics' 52 new #1s

Tags: discussion, blog, promotional-grant

Apologies for the possibly editable title. I'm about to propose a LOT of promotional grant ideas, so I want them to be easily identifiable. I want to give you guys free stuff!

DC Comics is relaunching their entire superhero universe this September with 52 new #1 issues, designed to be jumping on points for new readers due to either being rebooted completely (Superman, Wonder Woman) or streamlined (Batman, Green Lantern). You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_DC_Universe_reboot). This relaunch coincides with the company's big digital comics push; every comic book will be released simultaneously in both a print and digital edition.

---

I am proposing that a limited number of our users, based on their rep, receive from Stack Exchange all 52 #1 issues in either digital or physical form. The person(s) who receive these 52 will generate a TBD number questions and blog content about the DC relaunch. A few notes:

- I am not sure completely sure if physical copies is doable. Ideally we want you to get your hands on them the day they are released in order to get content up as quickly as possible. Comic books have to be ordered months in advance and subscriptions to physical copies are notoriously late. Because of this, we might have to take advantage of the ol' Digital Revolution. If purchasing a gift card from your local comic store so you can use it to buy the new 52 is preferable (believe me, I understand the power of the physical copy), then that can most likely be arranged.
- Based on the interest of the community and whether or not I can get DC Comics to contribute to this project (I haven't reached out to my DC contacts yet as user interest will determine if I need to), I don't know how many people we can give this to. I would like to do this for at least two users. If more than one user is selected, it will be the ones with the highest reputation points at a TBD time.

---

I really hope this is sounds like a fun idea and, if it goes well, I can foresee it leading to a lot of other cool events in the future. What does everyone think?

Comment: I just throw this like that, but it may be more within the site's scope to give something like [Hugo Award Nominees](http://www.renovationsf.org/hugo-intro.php#nominees)?

Comment: That's definitely something that we can do in the future. I don't see why one would have to be done in place of the other; there's room for both in our site and in our budget. I'm hesitant about doing it right now only because the award ceremony is in five days, which doesn't seem to be enough time to gather the interested people and get copies to them. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I thought SE frowned on artificially generating questions?

Comment: I think that requiring users to write a certain number of questions and/or blog posts could be seen as artificial, yes. Maybe there shouldn't be a definite number? Regarding the act of giving it away, I think that's only artificial if the recipients are users who have no interest in the item promoted. But below we have two users who would most likely buy these comics anyway if money wasn't an issue; we're just taking away that issue. At least, that's my thinking.

Comment: @BrettWhite -  Totally unrelated, but if you guys are budget conscious as far as grants, and are thinking of LOTR grant, look at this deal that just popped into my RSS feed: http://www.techbargains.com/news_displayItem.cfm/278982

Comment: @BrettWhite - and scrolling down my RSS feed, http://www.techbargains.com/news_displayItem.cfm/278997

Answer (score 4):

I'll apply.  I'm a big-time DC reader, who's lapsed roughly 2 years ago, and would be able to provide something like a 'new reader jumping on' perspective.  As you can see from my history ([1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4230/1027), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4198/1027), [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2827/1027), and [4](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4485/1027)), I've answered and asked several comic-centric questions.  My favorite comics from when I was reading were the Superman, Flash, Green Lantern, JSA, and Justice League books, so I'll definitely be particularly detailed on those portions of the new 52.

I've sought to write for the blog, but life's been too hectic recently for me to make time.  Things are smoother now, so I'll be writing up a few things.

Comment: I second Keen as the obvious first choice for this.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the blog post way back when.

Answer (score 2):

I'm totally up for this. I asked a question previously about a good starting point, and would love a chance to actually be able to read/review the new start ups. I am completely new to the DC comic universe, so I would have a genuine "new user" point of view.

I'd also be willing to offer my review to the scifi blog.

Comment: Also, I have an iPad, so I can get the digital copies, too. I actually prefer digital to paper.

Comment: I have a physical copy of Justice League #1 on my desk right now to send to you! Can you email me your address? I am going to investigate getting you digital copies, but right now you have the physical edition. Thanks! brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com

Comment: You have email :) When you send it over, let me know what's expected review wise (if you know) so I can have an idea as to what if expected of me, lol.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the blog post way back when (also for the SW grant).

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, @Keen and @OghmaOsiris ! You have been selected for this mission, which you have chosen to accept (paraphrasing is always fun!). I've so far come up empty handed in my attempts to get these comics to you officially, but worry not! I will instead be mailing them to you; you should expect to see them on your proverbial doorstep on the Thursday after they come out.

Please email me at brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com with your mailing address. If you have any other questions about this grant, you can either post'em up here or include them in the email.

Comment: How are you going to ship them?  That'll affect which address you should send them to.

Comment: @Keen I believe they will be sent via FedEx, and if that changes I will be sure to let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Crap, is it too late to get in on this?

Comment: @Jack B Nimble Sadly, yes. I only have room in the budget for two sets of 52. BUT there will hopefully be a lot of offers similar to this in the future!